# Form validation logic

Tags: jquery, validation

I would like to validate a form via javascript/jquery.

Basically I would only like to validate input 2 **IF** input 1 has a value entered. Else do not validate it if box 1 is empty.

So validation for input 2 is only triggered if input 1 has any value entered in it.

I would ideally like to use some sort of library.

Thanks for any input in advanced.

Comment: You should [put more effort into researching and writing your question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/157574).  Also [see the very top result here](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=jquery+validation&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).

Comment: Arguably, the second result in the search is somewhat more useful, but yeah.  What he said.

Comment: @BenBarden: FYI, [this plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) and [this plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) are the **exact same** plugin.  ;-)

Comment: @Sparky672 Right - but the link off of docs.jquery.com is a lot better at telling you how to use the thing.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use a JavaScript if statement?

```
if($('#[input1]').val()!=""){
//validation here
}
```